# Single table inheritance in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using single table inheritance in JPA.

-Car
-- E-Car
-- Gasoline-Car

In my thymeleaf template, I access a list of the superclass (car) via for-each, in order to create a table with objects of both subclasses.

```
<tr th:each="car : ${cars}" 
th:class="${not car.isECar()} ? 'electricCar' : 'notECar'">
```

I now have the problem, that I want to access a property of a subclass, which does not exist in the other one.

```
<td th:text="'kWh ' + ${car.kwh}" style="vertical-align: center;">1025 kWh</td>
```

This throws following exception:

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field '...' cannot be found on object of type ...

Is there any way to render a html-tag, only if a property exists?

Comment: try th:if="${car.kwh!=null}"

Comment: @benkuly doesn't work because kwh cannot be found in the other subclass :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I now found a workaround:

First of all I wrote a method in the superclass car, which returns null. 
In my subclass E-Car, I overwrite the method which returns the proper value.

Now every car has a method called getKWH() and I can access it through:

```
<td th:text="${car.getKWH()} + ' kWh'" th:if="${car.getKWH()!=null}">2200 kWh</td>
```

Comment: i have same issue... but search a better solution